# Can React on Rails be integrated into an existing Rails 3.x app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-on-rails

The [prerequisites from the README](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/README.md#prerequisites) say "React on Rails supports older versions of Rails back to 3.x" so I was led to believe it could. But then during the install process I see I have to install webpacker. And there's the note "Rails/webpacker requires version 4.2+."

So I'm currently stalled out and wondering if this really does support Rails 3.x or if I misunderstood the documentation.

Is there a way to integrate React on Rails into an existing Rails 3.x app?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you raise an issue on the GitHub repo for `react_on_rails`? You might get a quick response there too.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh thanks, I forgot to mention I created this issue: https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/1137

Comment: The issue is closed now. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to justin808 on the corresponding GitHub issue for this question:

"React on Rails should not require rails/webpacker.

Just use the asset pipeline."

I guess I misunderstood that rails/webpacker was a hard dependency. Trying again now to get react_on_rails working without it. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, at least for now.